# javascript not going in to IF condition

Tags: javascript, servlets

My web app has javascript in there I need to check condition.
JS :

```
var getholiday="A";
var getHolidaysBydate = function (dates, id, did) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "checkroll/getDate.htm",
        data: {
            tag: "tagged",
            dates: dates,
            id: id,
            did: did
        },
        success: function (flag) {

            flag = eval(flag);
            //     var textbox = document.getElementById('get_holiday');
            // $.each(holidaysRelatedData.holidayMap,function(kk,v){
            //  $("#division").append("<option value="+kk+">"+v+"</option>");
            //     textbox.value = flag;
            getholiday = flag;
            //   })  



        },
        async: false

    });

}


$("#add-record").live("click", function () {

    var e = document.getElementById("empnum");
    var selectEmpID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var es = document.getElementById("division");
    var selectDivID = es.options[es.selectedIndex].value;


    getHolidaysBydate(jQuery.trim($("#datepicker").val()), selectEmpID, selectDivID);

    if ($(getholiday == "A") {
        bottomBar("Holiday for worker.", 'topbarred');
    }
}
```

getHolidaysBydate is mapped in servlet GET method.its work fine

GET :

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

String date=null;
int empid=0;
int divid=0;
String flag="B";
        Model checkRollModel = new Model();

        if (request.getParameter("dates")!= "" && request.getParameter("id")!= ""){

          date=request.getParameter("dates");
          empid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
          divid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("did"));

        }


        int val=checkRollModel.getHolidays(date,empid,divid);
        if(val>0)
        {
            flag="A";

        }

        response.setContentType("application/json");

        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(flag));
    }
```

if the condition is matching that must go into IF condition it didn't go?
What's wrong with code?

Comment: Almost stopped reading when I noticed `live()`, then I noticed `async:false` and stopped reading. Start over and write the code so it works with newer versions of jQuery (`live` has been removed) and the async nature of ajax.

Comment: You seem to have a syntax error `if($(getholiday == "A")`. The parenthesis doesn't match

Comment: Sorry code must be like this : 
 if(getholiday == "A"){
                     
                      bottomBar("Holiday for worker.",'topbarred'); 
                    }

Comment: Does it work when you change it to `if(getholiday == "A")`

Comment: No it's not going into IF condition.

Comment: is the data types different in getholiday variable and "A"?

Answer (score 0):

take out "$(" from your if condition. check in firebug console. you will be getting syntax error at this line.

Answer (score 0):

resolve the problem by using boolean.
var getholiday =true;
if(getholiday) {}

But I dont know why it not working with Strings. Not fermiliar with JS.